# Render function partly working, how can i fix this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

My render function doesn't work like expecting, i tried a few things, but i cannot understand why it isn't working. Can someone help me out ?
As you can see below it does create the `UL` element but not the `LI` element, same goes for both conditions.

```
render: function (createElement) {
    var list;
    if (this.items.length > 0) {
     list = createElement(
        'ul',
        {
          class: {
            'v7-modal-list': true
          }
        },
        this.items.map(function (item) {
          return createElement(
            'li',
            createElement(
              'label',
              [
              createElement(
                'span',
                item.name
              ),
              createElement(
                'input',
                {
                  attrs: {
                    type: "checkbox"
                  }
                }
              )
              ]
            )
          )
        })
      )
    } else {
      list = createElement(
        'ul',
        {
          class: {
            'v7-modal-list': true
          }
        },
        createElement(
          'li',
          {
            class: {
                "v7-modal-empty-list": true
            }
          },
          "Empty list"
        )
      )
    }

    return createElement(
      'div', [
      createElement(
        'h4',
        {
          class: {
            "v7-modal-title-4": true
          }
        },
        this.name
      ),
      list
    ]
    )
  }
```

**Output:**

```
<div><h4 class="v7-modal-title-4">Log::</h4><ul class="v7-modal-list"></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createElement` arguments: (nodeName, attributes, elements) as described https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments.

**Elements must be array** (or string if text node is used). It may be array in array as it will be flattened. So this code must work:

```js
      list = createElement(
        'ul',
        {
          class: {
            'v7-modal-list': true
          }
        },
        [createElement(
          'li',
          {
            class: "v7-modal-empty-list"
          },
          "Empty list"
        )]
      )
```

Commented out code is correct.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping and answer me, this is one of the things i did at first, the function was a thing i did try to fix it, the comment out is also not working.

Comment: Oke i found out your answer is correct, so stupid of me `[createElement(/**/)]` does work